# コード上のRubyのメソッドの順番を並び変える方法

Tags: ruby

こんにちは。Rubyに関する質問です。あるクラスに定義されているメソッドを、自動で並び替えたいのですがどうするとよいでしょうか？
たとえば、下記のようなたくさんのメソッドが定義されているクラスがあったとして、

```rb
class
  def z
    "z"
  end

  def y
    "y"
  end

  def x
    "x"
  end

  # 中略 ---

  def b
    "b"
  end

  def a
    "a"
  end
end
```

このコード上のメソッドの順番を名前の順番に並び替えたいとします。

```rb
class
  def a
    "a"
  end

  def b
    "b"
  end

  def c
    "c"
  end

  # 中略 ---

  def y
    "y"
  end

  def z
    "z"
  end
end
```

今回はたまたまreverseしているだけですが、メソッドはランダムに並んでいて、並べかえたい順番は別に与えられているとします。どうするのが良いでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

強引な方法ですが、`source_location` と `eval` を使って処理しています。前提として、対象のソースコードファイルには一つのクラス定義のみが記述されていて、インスタンスメソッド以外の宣言・定義は無視されます(出力されません)。

**TestClass.rb**

```
class TestClass
  def z
    "z"
  end

  def y
    "y"
  end

  def x
    "x"
  end

  def b
    "b"
  end

  def a
    "a"
  end

  def h
    if true
      puts "h"
    end
  end

  def w; "w" end
end
```

**sort_method.rb**

```
src_file = './TestClass.rb'
src = IO.readlines(src_file)

cls = ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).to_a
load src_file
new_cls = (ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).to_a - cls)[0]

printf("class %s\n", new_cls)
new_cls.instance_methods(false).sort.each {|name|
  _, start = new_cls.instance_method(name).source_location
  next if !start
  start -= 1
  i = 1
  loop do
    begin
      eval src[start, i].join
    rescue SyntaxError
      i += 1  
      next
    end
    break
  end  
  puts src[start, i].join, "\n"
}
puts 'end'
```

**実行**

```
$ ruby sort_method.rb

class TestClass
  def a
    "a"
  end

  def b
    "b"
  end

  def h
    if true
      puts "h"
    end
  end

  def w; "w" end

  def x
    "x"
  end

  def y
    "y"
  end

  def z
    "z"
  end

end
```